# HTML to PDF Rocket - PDF Generation

Tags: html, css, image, azure, pdf-generation

I'm trying to convert an HTML to PDF from a azure website that contains images and css files like "bootstrap".

My Code (the same as they tutorial for this cases - MVC c# - http://www.html2pdfrocket.com/Examples/CSharp)

```
string apiKey = "MY KEY";
string value = html; // SOME HTML IN STRING FORMAT

using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                // Build the conversion options
                NameValueCollection options = new NameValueCollection();
                options.Add("apikey", apiKey);
                options.Add("value", value);

                // Call the API convert to an image
                byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://api.html2pdfrocket.com/pdf", options);

                // Save the image to disk
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/somepdf.pdf"), result);
            }
```

The code is generating the pdf file but without the css styles and images.

How can I fix this problem?

The html is realy simple, just have a table, one image and one css file "bootstrap"

The image I want to show in the html is placed like this:

```
 <img id="image" src="~/Images/someimage.jpg" >
```

and the CSS file is:

```
<link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have some CSS classes like this too:

```
#header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I already tryied place the full path of the image and of the "bootstrap" but it still not working.

Comment: What did you end up doing to solve this? I currently have the same question.

Comment: Hello @emragins, 
Well, I ended up using another solution - NReco:  http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx
They have a free version and it is working very well on my projects.

Comment: Hmm... I had tried that and it didn't seem to work on azure websites.  Maybe I'll have to look at it again.  (But more and more I'm thinking I just need to switch to VM -- problem solved.)  Thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: My temporary solution is using the bootstrap CDN and in-lining any additional css.  I'm building the html up with razor and just made a partial view I can include for my common "print" css.  Embedding images as base64 strings would work, too...

Comment: Yes, NReco is a problem if you are using Azure, I had to create an Web Role to make it work

Answer (score 4):

You only need change all link to a full address like

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/Scripts/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Or create a html page and send this html page's url to the API.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure websites you can use the [HTML to PDF for Azure](http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx) solution from EvoPdf. The package you can download from website contains a demo Azure Website. The demo source code is below:

```
protected void convertToPdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the server IP and port
    String serverIP = textBoxServerIP.Text;
    uint serverPort = uint.Parse(textBoxServerPort.Text);

    // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
    HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter(serverIP, serverPort);

    // Set optional service password
    if (textBoxServicePassword.Text.Length > 0)
        htmlToPdfConverter.ServicePassword = textBoxServicePassword.Text;

    // Set HTML Viewer width in pixels which is the equivalent in converter of the browser window width
    htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerWidth = int.Parse(htmlViewerWidthTextBox.Text);

    // Set HTML viewer height in pixels to convert the top part of a HTML page 
    // Leave it not set to convert the entire HTML
    if (htmlViewerHeightTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        htmlToPdfConverter.HtmlViewerHeight = int.Parse(htmlViewerHeightTextBox.Text);

    // Set PDF page size which can be a predefined size like A4 or a custom size in points 
    // Leave it not set to have a default A4 PDF page
    htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = SelectedPdfPageSize();

    // Set PDF page orientation to Portrait or Landscape
    // Leave it not set to have a default Portrait orientation for PDF page
    htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = SelectedPdfPageOrientation();

    // Set the maximum time in seconds to wait for HTML page to be loaded 
    // Leave it not set for a default 60 seconds maximum wait time
    htmlToPdfConverter.NavigationTimeout = int.Parse(navigationTimeoutTextBox.Text);

    // Set an adddional delay in seconds to wait for JavaScript or AJAX calls after page load completed
    // Set this property to 0 if you don't need to wait for such asynchcronous operations to finish
    if (conversionDelayTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        htmlToPdfConverter.ConversionDelay = int.Parse(conversionDelayTextBox.Text);

    // The buffer to receive the generated PDF document
    byte[] outPdfBuffer = null;

    if (convertUrlRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        string url = urlTextBox.Text;

        // Convert the HTML page given by an URL to a PDF document in a memory buffer
        outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(url);
    }
    else
    {
        string htmlString = htmlStringTextBox.Text;
        string baseUrl = baseUrlTextBox.Text;

        // Convert a HTML string with a base URL to a PDF document in a memory buffer
        outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlString, baseUrl);
    }

    // Send the PDF as response to browser

    // Set response content type
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

    // Instruct the browser to open the PDF file as an attachment or inline
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename=Getting_Started.pdf; size={1}",
        openInlineCheckBox.Checked ? "inline" : "attachment", outPdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));

    // Write the PDF document buffer to HTTP response
    Response.BinaryWrite(outPdfBuffer);

    // End the HTTP response and stop the current page processing
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Please declare your affiliation with the EvoPdf in the body of the answer.